# Rails 3 migrating from MySQL to Oracle

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, oracle, database-migration

What kind of potential problems can be raised during migration from MySQL database to Oracle database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm neither a MySQL nor a RoR expert, but I'll give it a go:
 - maximum text column length  (Oracle supports only 4000 chars, for longer ones you have to use CLOBs)
 - Oracle treats '' (empty strings) as NULL
 - Oracle object names have a maximum length of 30 chars (tables, views, columns, ...)
Have a look at 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems
for further differences.